# Rename the Controller Name in the URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have 2 brands which use the same controller. In one brand the URL must look like ~Home/Index and in other URL should look like ~Account/Index, but the both URLs must point to the same Home Controller action methods.

Please give any idea how to achieve this.

Comment: In the `Index()` method of `Account`, do a redirect to `/Home/Index`

Comment: I have only one controller "Home". But the Url should appear like Account for the brand2.

Comment: Then create a route - `url: "Account/Index", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }`

Answer (score 0):

Specify 2 route in the `RouteConfig.cs`

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "Home/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );               

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default1",
               url: "Account/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
```

Use this URL to call the `Index()` method in `Home` controller

1) http://localhost/../Home/Index

2) http://localhost/../Account/Index

Answer (score 0):

**Put below code inside Global.asax.cs**

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                           name: "Account",
                           url: "Account/Index",
                           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );
   routes.MapRoute(
                            name: "Default",
                            url: "Home/Index",
                            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );
```

*Note:**Always Default name put in last line in golbal.asax.cs**